# Joomla - echo section name

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to put some php in my Joomla template to call the active section name at a very specific location.

I can get the active menu title with this code

```
(at the top of my file, also used for something else)
<?php
    $menu =& JSite::getMenu();
    $active = $menu->getActive();
    $params = $menu->getParams( $active->id );
    $class = $params->get( 'pageclass_sfx' );
?>

<?php echo JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->name ?>
```

but I haven't found a way to call the active section title.

Let me know if you can help. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't really test this but it should get it done

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); // if you havent included already
$thisArticle=JRequest::getInt( 'id');// gets current article id
$query = 'SELECT sectionid FROM #__content WHERE id = ' . $thisArticle;// query to get the secton id
$db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);
$thisSectionID = $db->loadResult();
$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM jos_sections WHERE id = "$thisSectionID"'; // query to get the section title from section id
$db->setQuery($query2);
$column= $db->loadResultArray();
$sectionTitle = $column['2'] ; // variable to post section title
```

you could probably do this all in one query too, with a join

Comment: Thank you for your help. Looks good and clean, but unfortunately I can't get it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

Found a chunk of code on the web - which I modified to suit my needs :

Original code (output Section:Category)

```
    <?php
   defined('_JEXEC') OR defined('_VALID_MOS') OR die( "Direct Access Is Not Allowed" );
   $str = '';
   $str =& JRequest::getVar('id');
   $aStr = explode(":",$str);
   $id = $aStr[0];

   if ($id > 0) {
          $db = JFactory::getDBO();
          $query = "SELECT jos_sections.title as stitle, jos_categories.title as ctitle
            FROM jos_content
            LEFT JOIN jos_sections ON jos_content.sectionid = jos_sections.id
            LEFT JOIN jos_categories ON jos_content.catid = jos_categories.id
            WHERE jos_content.id = " . $id;
          $db->setQuery($query);
      $titles = $db->loadObjectList();
      echo " " . $titles[0]->stitle . ": " . $titles[0]->ctitle;

   }
?>
```

My version :

```
<?php
   defined('_JEXEC') OR defined('_VALID_MOS') OR die( "Direct Access Is Not Allowed" );
   $str = '';
   $str =& JRequest::getVar('id');
   $aStr = explode(":",$str);
   $id = $aStr[0];

   if ($id > 0) {
          $db = JFactory::getDBO();
          $query = "SELECT jos_sections.title as stitle
            FROM jos_content
            LEFT JOIN jos_sections ON jos_content.sectionid = jos_sections.id
            WHERE jos_content.id = ".$id;
          $db->setQuery($query);
          $titles = $db->loadObjectList();
      echo '<span class="componentheading">'.$titles[0]->stitle.'</span>';

   }

   else {
      echo '<h1>'.JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->name.'</h1>';
   }

?>
```

It gets the section name and if it can't get nothing, it will get the active menu item related, if there's one.

Hope it can helps someone! Took me a while to get this working.

Last thing : it works with Joomfish - translation component